# Problem connecting to Database

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I just got a mail from my DB adminstrator with these details

The environment is :

```
Server :      hpsd1805
Listener :    1234
SID :         pingo11
ServiceName : ikrdevo01
Login :       jam_adm
Passwd :      jam_adm_01
```

So how can i start using this DB.. What is url here?

Now I want to connect to the database and to create some tables..

When I use this URL :jdbc:oracle:thin:@hpsd1805:1234:pingo11

resulted in this exception :java.sql.SQLException: Exception d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Exception d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Exception d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Exception d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general syntax is

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid
```

In your case it is

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hpsd1805:1521:hpsd1805
```

Assumin, the Oracle instance listener is listening on port 1521